# line contracts and expands in html

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

i want to make a line that contracts and expands along x-axis randomly it should start from the middle of canvas . I was only able to move the line one way, not both ways! i have the code, if you could please help me i would really appreciate it !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<style>
    canvas {
        border: solid;
        border-color: black; }
</style>
```

```
<canvas id="canvas">
</canvas>
<script>

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    var posX = 0;
    var lineLength = 50;
    var speed = 2;

    function drawLine() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(posX, 50);
        ctx.lineTo(posX + lineLength, 50);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function moveLine() {
        posX += speed;
        if (posX < 0 || posX > canvas.width - 50) {
            speed = speed * -1;
        }
    }

    function loop() {
        // clear old frame;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        moveLine();
        drawLine();
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to be modifying the value of `lineLength` in your loop, not `posX`. Like this:

```
function moveLine() {
    lineLength += speed;
    if (lineLength < 0 || lineLength > canvas.width - 50) {
        speed = speed * -1;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to center your line:

```
function drawLine() {
    var center = canvas.width/2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(center - (lineLength/2), 50);
    ctx.lineTo(center + (lineLength/2), 50);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Since the X position of your line isn't variable, you don't need `posX` at all.